# Unable to select the correct first row in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table row with 6 rows. I want to have the background colour of the first row to be different but the background color of 4th row ( index 3 ) also changes. I am adding the screenshot of the same and here is the code

```
import UIKit
var items = ["admksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNC","badmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNC", "cadmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNCSDNSAJKDNAKLSMDLAKSDMKLASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMLAKSMDLASMDLAKSMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMLKADSMLKASMDLKASMDLKMadmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNCishan","cool1","hsjndjksndjkasnd","nsjdnknkjandjknasdka"]
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {
let basicCellIdentifier = "BasicCell"
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
func configureTableView() {

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier) as BasicCell
    if ( indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }
    println(indexPath.row)
    cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }



   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(items.count)
    //tableView.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

[image: 4th row's background changing]

Comment: Remove cell.userInteractionEnabled = false from your code.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. How does it make a difference? I want to some properties only for the first row but it is happening for the fourth row as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are reusing your cells via `dequeueReusableCell` with identifier as-

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier) as BasicCell
```

according to your requirements you have the background color of the cell for index path 0 to gray color as

```
if ( indexPath.row == 0)
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

When this cell is reused for the 4th row(index path.row = 3), than it already has the background color set earlier for row 0 (to gray color), that's why all the reused cell which are reusing the cell of 0th index will be shown with the gray color.

To resolve this issue just add the else case with the above if statement as

```
if ( indexPath.row == 0)
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor() 
else
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```